# List of Research Institutes (excluding universities)!

Tags: international-students, science, international, ranking, student-exchange

> There are many international rankings/lists for universities (e.g. QS ranking). However, I am interested in an science institute ranking/list that does **not** involve universities.

Let me give you an idea of what I am searching for: I am from Germany and I know that a major part of scientific progress is happening in universities. Nevertheless there are institutions such as *Max-Planck-Institute for Mathematics* (Germany), or *German Aerospace Center* (DLR), or *Weizmann Institute of Science* (Israel), or *CERN* (Switzerland), or *Perimeter Institute for Theoretical Physics* (Canada), with great significance in science. These institutions do not appear in any ranking, any list of science institutes, or my Google search for "*science institutes*".

> So where can I find a list of such institutions, e.g. by subject?

Question background: (1) I am curious in general to find a list/ranking that includes such non-teaching institutions too. (2) I went for several internships to science institutes, e.g. DLR/CERN. I am in my bachelor studies and currently searching for new internship opportunities during the summer vacation period. There are a lot of great opportunities in Germany, but I would like to spend this summer in some foreign institute (that is not an university) - to gain international experiences and because German scholarships (ironically) only financially support internships that are in foreign countries. However, in this context I am struggling to find such institutes... For example: I was looking for science institutes in Japan, but I only found the main universities.

**Important Note:** The ranking is **not** the important thing to me, but a **list** to have an overview!

Comment: Read through the affiliations of authors in a journal.

Comment: Well, of course #1 will be IAS (Princeton), and #2 will be IHES. The only question is what will be #3 and lower..

Comment: @user386359, thanks for your excellent and accurate spontaneous ranking! But may I ask what is IHES?

Comment: @Dilworth Are you saying that none of the names Grothendieck, Thom, Connes, Deligne, Kontsevich, Lafforgue (all Fields medaillists), Gromov, Ruelle,... sound familiar? It is not an "anthill" (thousands of average scientists, only a handful of brilliant ones) institute like CERN.

Comment: Most of them are very familiar, of course. Still, never have I heard of IHES. But I'm happy to learn new things.

Comment: Having rankings for universities is already a bad mistake. Why having another one?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I agree in parts... However, that is why I explicitly added **list** to the explanation! The first wish of mine is to simply **find** such foreign institutes, regardless of the any ranking.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I think opposite, we need to rank institutes bcs it is good field for freeloaders in academia

Comment: @SSimon I don't understand what you mean by "freeloader" and what is the connection with ranking institutes.

Comment: It means "a person who takes advantage of others' generosity without giving anything in return." @MassimoOrtolano many of them at institutes

Comment: @SSimon I don't think you have a clear understanding of research institutes, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano what you mean? It is serious problem around Europe, PhD stacked in institutes on salaries, never published as first author or corresponding author for 20 years, 10, or 5, on permanent contracts.

Comment: @SSimon I agree with Massimo. You seem to generalize some limited personal experience.

Comment: @Roland Limited? why there is than so many paper and statistic telling otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further search I found exactly what I was looking for:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Research_institutes

or by country:

> **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Research_institutes_by_country**

This comprehensive list includes the majority of all existing research institutes and definitely all notable one's. However, there is of course no ranking provided (which is not a problem for me but may be for other people that visit this question).